# Why is python's built in sum function slow when used to flatten a list of lists?

Tags: python-2.7

When trying to flatten a list of lists using python 2.7's built-in `sum` function, I've ran across some performance issues  - not only was the computation slow, but the iterative approach yielded much faster results.

The short code below seems to illustrate this performance gap:

```
import timeit

def sum1(arrs):
    return sum(arrs, [])

def sum2(arrs):
    s = []
    for arr in arrs:
        s += arr
    return s

def main():
    array_of_arrays = [[0] for _ in range(1000)]
    print timeit.timeit(lambda: sum1(array_of_arrays), number=100)
    print timeit.timeit(lambda: sum2(array_of_arrays), number=100)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

On my laptop, I get as output:

```
>> 0.247241020203
>> 0.0043830871582
```

Could anyone explain to me why is it so?

Comment: I assume that by now you've found `itertools.chain`?

Comment: Didn't know about it, thanks! It looks that the most straightforward constructor to use in this case would be `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, since it wouldn't require any unpacking (not that there would be any significant performance difference between the two constructors - it just looks nicer IMO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sum2` uses `+=`:

```
    for arr in arrs:
        s += arr
```

`sum` does not use `+=`. `sum` is defined to use `+`. The difference is that `s += arr` is allowed to perform the operation by *mutating the existing `s` list*, while `s = s + arr` must construct a new list, copying the buffers of the old lists.

With `+=`, Python can use an efficient list resizing strategy that requires an amount of copying proportional to the size of the final list. For `N` lists of length `K` each, this takes time proportional to `N*K`.

With `+`, Python cannot do that. For every `s = s + arr`, Python must copy the entire `s` and `arr` lists to construct the new `s`. For `N` lists of size `K` each, the total time spent copying is proportional to `N**2 * K`, much worse.

Because of this, you should pretty much never use `sum` to concatenate sequences.

Comment: Once I modified `s += arr` to `s = s+arr`, the performance detoriated. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: I thought some sort of "pure C" code invocation would be behind this gap - pretty cool that it's so embedded in python itself. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't they use the `+=` operator in the `sum` function?

Comment: @BernardoAmorim: Probably to avoid unexpectedly mutating objects. Note that sequence concatenation is not an intended use case of `sum`, and `sum` even prohibits the `start` value from being a string.