# Python: Reconstruct a list by its element counts

Tags: python, numpy

I had a list with several elements (0,1,2,3,...)

Now I have a dict with above unique elements as keys, their counts as values:

```py
{0:1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:6}
```

And I want to reconstruct it back to a list

```py
[0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Is there any pythonic way the achieve this? vanilla or with numpy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({0:1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:6})

list(c.elements())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use *sum()* for this:

```
d = {0:1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:6}
d = sum([[k]*v for k,v in d.items()], [])
```

Comment: This is correct but slow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032630/why-is-pythons-built-in-sum-function-slow-when-used-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists
It's much faster if you replace method of concatenation of your list with `itertools.chain(..)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a `numpy` way:

```
d = {0:1, 1:3, 2:4, 3:6}
np.repeat(list(d.keys()), list(d.values()))
```