# How do I combine lists in column of dataframe to a single list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

Some context, I have some data that I'm doing some text analysis on, I have just tokenized them and I want to combine all the lists in the dataframe column for some further processing.

My df is as:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['issue regarding app', 'graphics should be better'], 'text': [["'app'", "'load'", "'slowly'"], ["'interface'", "'need'", "'to'", "'look'", "'nicer'"]]})`
```

I want to merge all the lists in the 'text' column into one list, and also remove the open/close inverted commas.

Something like this:

```
lst = ['app', 'load', 'slowly', 'interface', 'need', 'to', 'look', 'nicer']`
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish that with the use of `apply` and `lambda`

The use of `apply` method is
to apply a function to each element
in the `'text'` column while
the `sum` function is to
concatenate all the lists together

```py
lst = sum(df["text"].apply(lambda x: [i.replace("'", "") for i in x]), [])
```

Output:

```
['app', 'load', 'slowly', 'interface', 'need', 'to', 'look', 'nicer']
```

If you want to replace multiple elements like `"'“` and `"a"`, `translate` will be efficient instead of `replace`:

```py
trans = str.maketrans("", "", "'a")
lst = sum(df["text"].apply(lambda x: [i.translate(trans) for i in x]), [])
```

Comment: Using `sum` to flatten a list of lists might look fancy, but [it's inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032630/why-is-pythons-built-in-sum-function-slow-when-used-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists).

Comment: What should we do if we want to apply (replace) two things?

Comment: It returned me with a list that looked something like this, `['[',
 '',
 'a',
 'p',
 'p',
 '',
' ',
 'l',
 'o',
 'a',
 'd',
 '',
...]`

Comment: @ShahriyarShamsipour I added responde to your question al the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Qaaqq11282211 I think you might be missing out something. The code I provided works well just like expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
out = [x.strip("'") for l in df['text'] for x in l]
```

Output:

```
['app', 'load', 'slowly', 'interface', 'need', 'to', 'look', 'nicer']
```

Comment: What should we do if we want to apply strip() to two things?

Comment: What do you mean by "*two things*"?

Comment: Two characters. For example, just as you remove the " ' ", remove the " a " as well.

Comment: It depends how. You can try `strip("'a")` to remove both `'` and `a` characters. If this doesn't do what you want, please provide explicit examples in your question.

Comment: I tried this too, but it also returned me with something like this, the same as above,
 `['[',
 '',
 'a',
 'p',
 'p',
 '',
' ',
 'l',
 'o',
 'a',
 'd',
 '',
...]`

Comment: @Qaaqq11282211 this means you don't have lists but a string representation (the provided example is incorrect). Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert.

Answer (score 2):

We can also iterate through each list in the series and concatenate them using append() and finally use concat() to convert them to a list. Yields the same output as above.